# Want ThreadPoolExecutor to execute tasks instantly

Tags: java, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

I have a ThreadPoolExecutor with one thread that will be used for batch processing, So before assigning a new task to the executor i have to wait for the earlier task to complete, i was doing this by depending upon the value for active jobs, but seeing in detail i found that, the executor doesn't executes the task instantly.

The problem this is causing to me is that i am ready to give the next batch but the first task  has not yet started thus the value of active jobs is 0.

How can i get to run the task instantly. I am also OK with any other executor or way that this can be done.

Comment: You get a Future back when you submit() tasks to a thread pool executor. Store that return value and you can just wait on that Future to make sure your prior tasks have finished. However is there any particular reason you must wait for earlier tasks to complete before submitting new batch jobs ?

Comment: Well if you have a pool with 1 thread and you need to wait before submitting the next task, then you do not need any threadpool...

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to achive : if you want to wait for the earlier task to complete why would you use an executor ?

Comment: The scenario is that i have a lot of data which will be processed and then written to a file, so all this will be done in batches. So once i have processed a fixed amount of data it is given to the writer thread which is the executor and continue to process more data, but before i give the next batch to the writer, i should wait for the earlier job because they may write to the same file.

Comment: @user996808 if you have a ThreadPoolExecutor with only 1 thread, your jobs will be executed in the order you submit jobs to it, one job at a time. And naturally the executor queues up jobs if it isn't finished with the current job - so in such a case you don't need to wait for earlier jobs before submitting a new job.

Comment: Yes sure, but the complication is that my main thread decided when to shutdown the executor, but what i am seeing is that because the execution takes place sometime in future i am not able to wait properly using the avtiveCount, so i am shutting the executor but still some of the tasks that i have submitted where never scheduled.

Answer (score 2):

You should probably use `submit` method from `ExecutorService` to schedule your tasks. Here is a working program that uses single thread executor to run 10 tasks. I casted to `ThreadPoolExecutor` to monitor thread pool state. You can wait for a single task by calling `get` on its corresponding `Future` instance or wait for all the tasks by invoking `awaitTermination`. If you don't need result from the `Future` just use `Void`. Hope it helps.

```
public class Main {                                                                                                                             
    static class TimingCallable implements Callable<Long> {                                                                                     
        static int MIN_WAIT = 200;                                                                                                              
        @Override                                                                                                                               
        public Long call() {                                                                                                                    
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();                                                                                            
            try {                                                                                                                               
                Thread.sleep(MIN_WAIT + new Random().nextInt(300));                                                                             
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {                                                                                                  
                //DO NOTHING                                                                                                                    
            }                                                                                                                                   
            return System.currentTimeMillis() - start;                                                                                          
        }                                                                                                                                       
    }                                                                                                                                           

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {                                                    

        ExecutorService executor =  Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);                                                                            
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")                                                                                                          
        Future<Long>[] futureResults = new Future[10];                                                                                          
        for(int i =0; i < futureResults.length; i++) {                                                                                          
            futureResults[i] = executor.submit(new TimingCallable());                                                                           
            System.out.println(String.format("ActiveCount after submitting %d tasks: ", i+1) + ((ThreadPoolExecutor)executor).getActiveCount());
            System.out.println(String.format("Queue size after submitting %d tasks: ", i+1) + ((ThreadPoolExecutor)executor).getQueue().size());
        }                                                                                                                                       
        Thread.sleep(2000);                                                                                                                     
        System.out.println("ActiveCount after 2 seconds: " + ((ThreadPoolExecutor)executor).getActiveCount());                                  
        System.out.println("Queue size after 2 seconds: " + ((ThreadPoolExecutor)executor).getQueue().size());                                  
        for(int i =0; i < futureResults.length; i++) {                                                                                          
            if (futureResults[i].isDone()) {                                                                                                    
                System.out.println(String.format("%d task is done with execution time: ", i) + futureResults[i].get());                         
            }                                                                                                                                   
        }                                                                                                               //Waiting for the last task to finish
        System.out.println("Waiting for the last task result: " + futureResults[9].get());
        executor.shutdown();
        executor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);                                  
    }                                                                                                                                           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are having only one thread to execute just use LinkedQueue for storing jobs once thread is done with the execution then only it will pick another task.

```
ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1,1, TimeUnit.MINUTES, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>());
```

Also you can have different strategies if you restricting size

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

Read Rejected tasks

Comment: But how can I wait for the first task to complete

Answer (score 0):

## Single thread pool executor service

Apparently you want to run multiple tasks immediately but in the order submitted.

Quite easy: Use an **[executor service](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) backed by a single thread**. The executor buffers up the tasks while waiting on earlier ones to complete. With on a single thread in the thread pool, only one task at a time can be executed, so they will be done sequentially in the order submitted.

The [`Executors`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) class provides a choice of a few different thread pools backing an executor service. You want [`Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor()).

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor() ;
```

Submit a series of [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runnable.html) or [`Callable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) objects. Each represents a task to be executed.

```
es.submit(  ( ) -> System.out.println( "Hello. " + Instant.now() )  ) ;
es.submit(  ( ) -> System.out.println( "Bonjour. " + Instant.now() )  ) ;
es.submit(  ( ) -> System.out.println( "Aloha. " + Instant.now() )  ) ;
es.submit(  ( ) -> System.out.println( "Ciào. " + Instant.now() )  ) ;
es.submit(  ( ) -> System.out.println( "Shwmai. " + Instant.now() )  ) ;
```

Optionally, you can capture the [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) object returned by each call to `submit` if you want to track completion of the tasks. (not shown in code above)

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/xHrcWK).

> Hello. 2019-11-29T09:10:13.426987Z
>
> Bonjour. 2019-11-29T09:10:13.472719Z
>
> Aloha. 2019-11-29T09:10:13.473177Z
>
> Ciào. 2019-11-29T09:10:13.473479Z
>
> Shwmai. 2019-11-29T09:10:13.473974Z